# How to use docfx for git repo url?

Tags: c#, json, .net, docfx

how to use docfx where i have my source `docfx.json` from `github or devops repo url`?

which way is feasible to `use exe or nuget`?

i have one UI page where user will enter there repo path which has docfx.json

I tried:

1. docfx.exe but it won't take http url as a input parameter it only run on local  VM is not best solution for exe.
2. docker image but not a best approach either
3. nuget but how to use it as a central project where i will pass repo url and generate doc

Comment: What do you mean that you will pass a different repo URL every time?

Comment: I have one UI page , there user will enter his own repo path which has its docfx.json
i want to take that docfx.json from that given repo and generate html docs using docfx

Comment: kindly help with approach

Comment: Can you git clone docfx.json from the repo locally and generate the site that way?

Comment: I can clone but it should not be manual process.  user enter repo url in UI textbox filed and press submit button in backend some job have to do it. 
main catch is how to run docfx.exe as it takes only local path.

Comment: Could you set up an automatic trigger for an ADO pipeline when a URL is submitted? The first task could clone the submitted repo. The second task could use the docfx build task offered in the ADO marketplace. It would point to the cloned docfx.json on the build server. That may be slightly more automated...?

Comment: yes this is useful . any other approach using nuget we can think of ? in above ADO approach we can not run more parallels ADO pipelines.